# Build a quick Dashboard using react as front-end and data source as Elasticsearch ( Back-end Perl/Node/Any)

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

I am trying to build a quick interactive Dashboard using react as front-end and data source as Elasticsearch ( Back-end Perl/Node/Any.

To kick start, I need some help/suggestion. Is there any existing React template code to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may like to checkout [MUI Library](https://mui.com/) and their [prebuilt dashboards](https://mui.com/store/) so you can customize and work on them however the prebuilt ones are mostly paid with a couple of free alternatives. Also, note the prebuilt dashboards are made with the nextjs technology.

Here is another one called [Ant Design](https://ant.design/) (which I have not personally worked with but seems fairly neat and straightforward)

You could go through [this post](https://technostacks.com/blog/react-component-libraries) to see if you find anything you like in here